# Is it legit in firestore security rules using $(request.auth.token.email) to verify accessing users' own data?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm developing an app with two kinds of permission roles (admin and member). Every time an admin adds a member or another admin, he just needs to add them using their specific email address. In this situation, those emails are not required whether registered or not, and also those users can be added offline.

The problem is when an admin tries to add a member with an email, I can't add that member user id (probably a new member) to the 'users' collection but can add using his/her email address.

So, to be accessed their own data, I'm wondering whether it is recommended to use $(request.auth.token.email) instead of $(request.auth.uid) recommended in firebase security documentation. And also, if you have any suggestions, please let me know. I am very new to firebase security rules.

```
match /shops/{shop} {
  allow read, write: 
  if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/shops/$(shop)/users/$(request.auth.token.email))
  .data.admin == true;
}
```

[image: users collection under shops collection]

[image: my securiy rule condititon example].

Comment: I'm not totally sure how an admin adds a user but you can create a user in Firebase auth using the email that admin enters and then use that UID as Firestore doc ID in users collection. It's just easier to handle email changes with this and also just in case a user signs up email and then if you add Facebook auth, that account may have same email

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. 
I think you are missing part of my question. I just want them to be added in offline mode or those users may not be registered yet (in my app, I show its status as "pending user"). In those situations, you can't get userid from it.

Comment: The answer to "is it legit", depends on what legit mean to you in this context. I tried to answer some of the specifics below, but I recommend being explicit about which concerns you have around the legitimacy of your approach going forward.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I’m concerned that if I use email instead of uid as a rule condition, my rules will not be as strong as uid. And also, thanks for suggestion, I need to add email_verified conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prepopulate roles before the user's are registered, going by their email address is common.

You'll probably want to add a check if the email address is verified in that case, as otherwise anyone can register with one of the email addresses you have listen and gain administrative privileges.

Personally I'd see the mapping from email address to role as a temporary step in this scenario, and store the permanent user record under their UID as is more common. You can even do that client-side, by allowing the user to write the role to their own profile as long as it matches what you have in the email-to-role mapping collection.